# Hair too rigid unable to get rid of right angle structure

Tags: mesh, particles, hair

My hair is not smooth and too stiff, how can I make it less of a right angle near the roots?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to add more control points to the hair particles. The goal is the add some extra control points near the scalp/head so hair can bend nicely there.

[image: Example of selected control points]

To do so, make sure `Selection Mode: Point` is active to see the points. Select all `roots` by using the menu. Then select the next points via the menu (`Select` → `Select More` or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>NumPad +</kbd>). Now you add another control point for each hair particle with `Particle` → `Subdivide`.

Extend the selection before subdivision or repeat the steps when you need more control points. The selection can also help you to comb or puff only the parts of the hair strands you want.

To see the effect you need to increase the number of path steps for the hair. There are 3 settings for this. One in the tool options for the `Particle Edit` mode. Then for the final `Render` and one more for the `Viewport Display`. The default values are 2 or 3, often too low to bend the hair properly.

[image: step settings]